Como escrever texto com emoji usando PHP-CLI?
Olá.
O seguinte código escreve texto no Terminal do Windows preenchendo o texto com caracteres até determinada largura. A largura do texto corresponde ao número de colunas do terminal (obtido por mode con).
Entretanto, quando o texto possui emojis, o texto escrito ultrapassa a largura determinada à razão de 1 caractere por cada emoji.
Eis um exemplo do e seu resultado:
$len = 120;//Largura, em colunas do terminal, obtida com mode con
$texto1 = 'Hello XX world!';//Texto para referência.
$padded1 = mb_str_pad($texto1, $len, '_', STR_PAD_BOTH, 'UTF-8');
echo $padded1;

echo PHP_EOL;

$texto2 = 'Hello  world!';
$padded2 = mb_str_pad($texto2, $len, '_', STR_PAD_BOTH, 'UTF-8');
echo $padded2;

O resultado obtido (considerando um terminal com 120 colunas de largura):

O arquivo PHP está em UTF-8, porém a página de códigos do Terminal é 850 (Latin-1).
Coisas que tentei, sempre com o mesmo resultado:
Alterar a página de códigos do terminal com chcp 65001;
Converter $texto2 para ISO-8859-1;
Eu realmente já pesquisei pelo manual do PHP e não encontrei o que poderia ser feito para que o tamanho do texto seja expandido por mb_str_pad de maneira adequada. Também pesquisei em outros sites, inclusive no SO e SOpt, sem sucesso.
Qualquer ajuda será bem-vinda, mesmo que seja para explicar que isso não vai funcionar de forma alguma.

Veja se o link te ajuda.

Não é um problema do PHP, e não é possível resolver nativamente com PHP, talvez com a lib COM você consiga implementar algo próprio. É muito importante notar que o tamanho da fonte não pode ser calculado tão facilmente, isso varia das fontes que o sistema usa, de configurações do usuário, e até mesmo de terminal para terminal... Mesmo em linguagens que fornecem acesso direto a APIs nativas do OS o calculo é complicado.

Sobre a dimensão da tela, ela pode variar, então o que você pode usar para tentar é executar o mode con com as função exec() ou shell_exec() e extrair as infos (Colunas:), geralmente assim: https://i.sstatic.net/Qsz2vrHn.png, assim poderá ter uma ideia. Note que isso não resolve o tamanho da fonte.

Eu pego as dimensões do terminal com mode con com shell_exec(). No código da pergunta é que eu simplifiquei ao máximo, por isso é que eu fixei o número de colunas.

O código sugerido pelo @Benilson funcionou nos testes iniciais. Vou fazer mais testes e implementar isso no código que estou desenvolvendo para ver se a solução se mantém em mais cenários.
